# MySQL ROW_NUMBER for multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, row-number

I have a table that looks like:

```
+-------------+--------+------------+
| Employee ID | Salary | Grievances |
+-------------+--------+------------+
| 101         | 70,000 | 12         |
| 102         | 90,000 | 100        |
| ...         | ...    | ...        |
+-------------+--------+------------+
```

And I want to find all employees who are in the **top-ten** for salary, but the **bottom-five** for grievances. I (think I) know how to do this in SQL Server using `ROW_NUMBER`, but how to do it in MySQL? I've seen the [goto question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql) on doing this, but it doesn't really apply to a multiple column ordering.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on "top-ten for salary, but the bottom-five for grievances." with example data or output required

Comment: You might want to provide sample data and desired results, or even the SQL Server query.

Comment: I thought it was pretty self-explanatory.  Grab all employees whose salary is among the ten highest salaries AND whose grievance count is among the five lowest grievance counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can do this with a self-join:

```
select s.*
from (select t.*
      from t
      order by salary desc
      limit 10
     ) s join
     (select t.*
      from t
      order by grievances asc
      limit 5
     ) g
     on s.employeeid = g.employeeid;
```